# Compare python list of dictionaries with tolerance on column order

Tags: python, list, hash, dictionary

```
    first = [{'a':'aaa','b':'ccc','c':'bbb','d':'ddd'},
             {'a':'bb','b':2,'c':1,'d':3},
             {'a':'cc','b':22,'c':11,'d':33}]

    second = [{'a':'aaa','b':'bbb','c':'ccc','d':'ddd'},
              {'a':'bb','b':1,'c':2,'d':3},
              {'a':'cc','b':11,'c':22,'d':33}]
```

table 2

```
    |'a'  | 'b' | 'c' |'d'  |
    |'aaa'|'bbb'|'ccc'|'ddd'|
    |'bb' |1    |2    |3    |
    |'cc' |11   |22   |33   |
```

table 1

```
    |'a'  | 'b' | 'c' |'d'  |
    |'aaa'|'ccc'|'bbb'|'ddd'|
    |'bb' |2    |1    |3    |
    |'cc' |22   |11   |33   |
```

In the tables above, the order of first row is same. The second row attributes are the primary keys. Even if their order change, but the values beneath are fine, they are equal

I have two tables and they transform to list of dictionaries in my code.The first row of the table is key for the dictionaries. I have to compare these two such that even if the column order changes from second row onward, the two entities are same. So in the example above, they are same.

In other words, the keys of dictionary are not the primary key for the table. the second row attributes are. How to write a code to perform such comparison.

Comment: Post an example where they are different.

Comment: It's not clear for me what you are trying to do....check if both lists contains the same dicts or they not?

Comment: I suggest that you also post both your dicts in a table format, and show what you are trying to compare. for now it is hard to grasp your intention.

Comment: first = [{'a':None,'b':'ccc','c':'bbb','d':'ddd'},
  {'a':'bb','b':2,'c':4,'d':3},
  {'a':'cc','b':22,'c':44,'d':33}]
if first is like this, the first and second are diffrent

Comment: @AbhisheshSharma -- add the formated tables to your question and explain, what are the fields you are comparing.

Comment: don't put it in the comments. [edit] your question instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function compare() compares if first and second match according to what I understood is your equality criteria, and returns True if they are equal.

```
first = [{'a':'aaa','b':'ccc','c':'bbb','d':'ddd'},
         {'a':'bb','b':2,'c':1,'d':3},
         {'a':'cc','b':22,'c':11,'d':33}]

second = [{'a':'aaa','b':'bbb','c':'ccc','d':'ddd'},
          {'a':'bb','b':1,'c':2,'d':3},
          {'a':'cc','b':11,'c':22,'d':33}]


def compare(first,second):
    for a,b in zip(first, second):
        vals_a = list(a.values())
        vals_b = list(b.values())

        vals_a.sort()
        vals_b.sort()

        if vals_a != vals_b:
            return False

    return True

print compare(first,second)
```

Comment: Thanks Sebastian and Gato !

Comment: This just compares the values, but they're not sorted by the key you asked for ... is this what you meant?

Comment: well not exactly but It takes me to write answer !

Answer (score 1):

If order of unique values doesn't matter and the keys can be ignored:

```
key = lambda d: set(d.values())
eq = all(a == b for a, b in zip(map(key, first), map(key, second)))
```

It seems you actually want to find out whether two tables have the same columns ignoring the column order:

```
def columns(table):
    values = lambda d: map(d.get, table[0]) # use same order for rows
    return zip(*[values(row) for row in table]) # transpose

def equal_columns(first, second):
    return sorted(columns(first)) == sorted(columns(second))
```